# filling combobox from JSON(by string)

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile, combobox

I just want to fill combobox by JSON. (using jquery mobile)
for example:
this is my string (JSON):

```
var response = [{
      "A":"a2",
      "B":"b2",
      "C":"c2"
     },
     {
      "A":"a3",
      "B":"b3",
      "C":"c3"
    },
    {
      "A":"a4",
      "B":"b4",
      "C":"c4"
    }];
```

and this is my code:

...

```
<div>
<h1>Choose:</h1>
    <select name="myDropDownA" id="myDropDownA">
        <option>myOption</option>  
    </select>
    <select name="myDropDownB" id="myDropDownB">
        <option>myOption</option>  
    </select>
    <script>
     $(response.A).each(function()
             {
                 var option = $('<option />');
                 option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);
                 $('#myDropDownA').append(option);
             });
    </script>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Mybutton" onclick="Mybutton" />
    </div>
```

I want myDropDownA to be the selecting option A, myDropDownB to be the selecting option B.
and it's not working. why?

Comment: Probably because `response.A` is `undefined`. `response` is an **array**. See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196). I'm also wondering what you think `this` is inside the `.each` callback. Where to do the `label` and `value` properties suddenly come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$each` is wrong. Check [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
var myDropDownA = $("#myDropDownA");
var myDropDownB = $("#myDropDownB");
$.each(response, function(index,obj)
{
     //alert(index + ": " + obj.A);
    myDropDownA.append($("<option />").val(obj.A).text(obj.A));
    myDropDownB.append($("<option />").val(obj.B).text(obj.B));
});
```

Working demo: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/EvEYx/)

Comment: you can further factorize the working demo code by reference to my latest updated answer. Good luck and enjoy.